# How does a Python genius iterate over a single value in a Python tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, loops

I have a dictionary named 'score' with keys that are tuples.
Each tuple is of the form (x, y, tag).

Some possible score initializations are:

```
score[(0, 1, 'N')] = 1.0
score[(0, 1, 'V')] = 1.5
score[(0, 1, 'NP')] = 1.2
score[(1, 2, 'N')] = 0.2
score[(1, 2, 'PP')] = 0.1
score[(1, 2, 'V')] = 0.1
```

I'd like to be able to keep x and y constant (e.g. 0, 1) and then iterate over the given values for tag (e.g. N, V, NP).

Any Python geniuses out there know of ways to do this? I'm looking for multiple options on this one. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like each contestant in this thread answers to their own version of the question. Could you be more specific about what exactly you're trying to achieve, e.g. what the code in question should return or print?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about a list comprehension:

```
[ x[2] for x in score.keys() if x[0:2] == (0,1)]
```

Comment: My +1. I prefer your `if` part.  The `.keys()` can be left out as it forces creating a list (not a big problem), and dictionaries are iterated through the keys implicitly.

Answer (score 8):

```
[tag for x,y,tag in score if x==0 and y==1]
```

Comment: I like your solution - it is cleaner than kgiannakakis's.

Comment: @Tadeck I agree except that kgiannakakis' explicit use of `.keys()` is clearer for people not used this python idiom where iterating through a dictionary iterates through the keys. Speaking of which, i don't use `.keys()` either :D

Comment: Pretty much what I'd do, but I'd make it a generator expression. `()` instead of `[]`

Comment: This looks like the most straight forward solution. However, I'm terribly new to Python. Can you help me out by providing a bit of code around this so that I have more context as to how to use it?

Comment: @Ussabin Given the score dict, this is all you need to do to get what you asked. This is a list comprehension that will return list of tags (eg, ['N', 'V', 'NP']). If you can be more specific about what you want people may be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to iterate over all elements and check if they key matches what you are looking for. However, you can do this nicely by using a filtered iterator:

```
elems = (item for item in score.iteritems() if item[0][:2] == (0, 1))
```

You could also use an iterator that only gives you the tag value and the element instead of the whole item tuples:

```
elems = ((item[0][2], item[1]) for item in score.iteritems() if item[0][:2] == (0, 1))
```

If you really just need the tag values and not the corresponding elements, you can do it even easier:

```
tags = [k[2] for k in score if k[:2] == (0, 1)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> score
{(0, 1, 'NP'): 1.2,
 (0, 1, 'V'): 1.5,
 (1, 2, 'N'): 0.2,
 (1, 2, 'PP'): 0.1,
 (1, 2, 'V'): 0.1}

>>> list(item for item in score.iteritems() if item[0][:2] == (0, 1))
[((0, 1, 'NP'), 1.2), ((0, 1, 'V'), 1.5)]

>>> list(((item[0][2], item[1]) for item in score.iteritems() if item[0][:2] == (0, 1)))
[('NP', 1.2), ('V', 1.5)]

>>> [k[2] for k in score if k[:2] == (0, 1)]
['NP', 'V']
```

Comment: Definitely learned something from your response, ThiefMaster. This will  come in handy down the line. Looks like the responses above are a bit more efficient, though. Thanks for taking the time to lend me your genius.

Comment: You should honor the time with an upvote. And regarding efficiency: There is not really a difference.

Comment: Yeah...appreciate the suggestion. However, my reputation is still below 15 (just started using SOF), and I can't vote up yet.

Answer (score 1):

My IQ is over 200 so I hope this counts:

```
score = {}
score[(0, 1, 'N')] = 1.0
score[(0, 1, 'V')] = 1.5
score[(0, 1, 'NP')] = 1.2
score[(1, 2, 'N')] = 0.2
score[(1, 2, 'PP')] = 0.1
score[(1, 2, 'V')] = 0.1

from itertools import groupby

def group_key(dict_key):
    return dict_key[:2]

sorted_keys = sorted(score)
for group_key, group_of_dict_keys in groupby(sorted_keys, key=group_key):
    print group_key
    print [(dict_key, score[dict_key]) for dict_key in group_of_dict_keys]

"""
(0, 1)
[((0, 1, 'N'), 1.0), ((0, 1, 'NP'), 1.2), ((0, 1, 'V'), 1.5)]
(1, 2)
[((1, 2, 'N'), 0.2), ((1, 2, 'PP'), 0.1), ((1, 2, 'V'), 0.1)]
"""
```

of course if you just want the tags by themselves then change the loop:

```
for group_key, group_of_dict_keys in groupby(sorted_keys, key=group_key):
    print group_key
    tags = [tag for x, y, tag in group_of_dict_keys]
    print tags
"""
(0, 1)
['N', 'NP', 'V']
(1, 2)
['N', 'PP', 'V']
"""
```

Comment: Your IQ does not matter, the quality of your answers matters. `sorted_keys = sorted(score.keys())` could (should) be replaced with `sorted_keys = sorted(score)`. As far as other parts of your answer are concerned, they are ok.

Comment: thanks, i'll edit my answer now. I added another answer using defaultdict fyi. +1 for noticing thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the tags then defaultdict will be the most simple option.

```
score = {}
score[(0, 1, 'N')] = 1.0
score[(0, 1, 'V')] = 1.5
score[(0, 1, 'NP')] = 1.2
score[(1, 2, 'N')] = 0.2
score[(1, 2, 'PP')] = 0.1
score[(1, 2, 'V')] = 0.1

from collections import defaultdict

dict_ = defaultdict(list)

for x,y,tag in score:
    dict_[x,y].append(tag)

#now get a result for any x,y we like:
print dict_[0,1]
"""['NP', 'N', 'V']"""
```