# How to view all elements of a Python Dictionary for Just One Value of one of the Elements in a Tuple Key

Tags: python, dictionary, key, tuples, multidimensional-array

For a Python Dictionary with a tuple key, how can only the part of the dictionary with one of the tuple elements set to a single value be displayed. Then also looking to delete those elements.

For example, the dictionary

```
testTrak = {(0,1): '+', (0,2): '-', (1,1): '34.0', (1,2): 'test'}
```

and I want to list only the elements with the first number of the `tuple = 1`; that is, I want to list only `(1,*)` where the asterisk represents a wild card; hence, only
`(1,1): '34.0'` and `(1,2): 'test'` would be listed.

It seems maybe some kind of slicing should work but don't see it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10546763/298479

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a Python genius iterate over a single value in a Python tuple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546745/how-does-a-python-genius-iterate-over-a-single-value-in-a-python-tuple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I misread your question. Here's the solution you need for pretty much any Python version:

```
>>> testTrak = {(0,1): '+', (0,2): '-', (1,1): '34.0', (1,2): 'test'}
>>> dict([(key, value) for key, value in testTrak.items() if key[0] == 1])
{(1, 2): 'test', (1, 1): '34.0'}
```

In Python 2.7+ you can write the less verbose version:

```
>>> testTrak = {(0,1): '+', (0,2): '-', (1,1): '34.0', (1,2): 'test'}
>>> {key:value for key, value in testTrak.items() if key[0] == 1}
{(1, 2): 'test', (1, 1): '34.0'}
```

Excluding the items is just a matter negating the if clause, if this is what you asked in the comments:

```
>>> testTrak = {(0,1): '+', (0,2): '-', (1,1): '34.0', (1,2): 'test'}
>>> {key:value for key, value in testTrak.items() if key[0] != 1}
{(0, 1): '+', (0, 2): '-'}
```

Comment: That nailed it. Also works for a more complex version. Thank you. (P.S> Do you have any recommendations for books, etc. that cover dictionaries in more detail like this. Haven't seen a Python book that is very rigorous on Dictionaries.)

Comment: To be honest, I've only read Dive into Python (http://www.diveintopython.net/) by Mark Pilgrim. Note that there's also a Python 3 version available at (http://www.diveintopython3.net/).

Other than that, my two everyday sources of knowledge for Python are the official docs (http://docs.python.org) and #python on freenode. You won't find more knowledgeable people than those guys on IRC.

Comment: One more thing -- best way to delete these items from this output?

Comment: To (effectively) delete, just used a second dictionary equal to expression NOT, since several Gigs of ram in pc should be plenty to accommodate this:
tempDict = {key:value for key, value in testTrak.items() if key[0] != 1}
testTrak = tempDict

Answer (score 1):

what you want is a prefix tree, the dictionary doesn't give you that built in. you have a few options:

1. you can filter the dictionary keys with `iterkeys()`, which has linear time complexity and will be very inefficient if the dictionary is large;
2. if memory is not the issue - create 2 dictionaries, one by tuples, one by first member mapping to lists. it will be fast but memory heavy.
3. the ideal approach would be to use a prefix tree data structure. I don't know any good python modules to do that (I've written one for my work but it's not open source), but I'm sure there are.